# How to dynamically pass multiple object instance to another class.

Tags: c#, dictionary

I need to pass object of one class as parameter in other class dynamically. I have following code which has to be customize.

---

```
  ABC abc = new ABC();
  abc.id = "E100";
  abc.type = ABCType.BB_UNIQUE;
  abc.typeSpecified = true;

  ABC t = new ABC();
  t.id = "I";
  t.yellowkey = MarketSector.Equity;
  t.yellowkeySpecified = true;
   t.type = ABCType.t;
   t.typeSpecified = true;

  ABC abc2 = new ABC();
  abc2.id = "GB";
  abc2.type = ABCType.ISIN;
  abc2.typeSpecified = true;

  ABCs i = new ABCs();
  i.abc = new abc[] { abc, abc2, t };
```

I was able to as follows To dynamically create the class object but i am not able to pass it to another class:

---

```
    string value = "E100,I";
    string[] id;
    id = value.Split(',');
    IDictionary<string, ABC> col = new Dictionary<string, ABC>();
    foreach (string val in id)
    {
        col[val] = new ABC();
        col[val].id = val;
     }
   ABCs i = new ABCs();
```

This part is where i am struggling 
         i.abc = new abc[] { abc, abc2, t }; 
How will i be able to pass dynamic object of IDictionary to i.abc? 
Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` interface has a `Values` property for every value contained in the `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` which returns an `ICollection<TValue>`.

After including the `System.Linq` namespace, the `ICollection<T>` interface gets an extension method `ToArray<T>()` which converts the collection to an array of type `T`.
So the solution for your problem should be the following line:

```
i.abc = col.Values.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but this is the error i get when i try your solution. "does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type"

Comment: You have to include the System.Linq namespace. See the MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb298736(v=vs.110).aspx
I edited my answer to include this detail.